# Php laravel com jasper report

Tags: php, laravel, jasper-reports

Estou utilizando o laravel como framework, e jasperphp para gerar o relatório, porém não consigo passar o banco pro jasper,  a maioria usa mysql para gerar o relatório, só que eu estou usando Mssql, alguém me da uma luz com isso por favor, das duas formas que tento passar o banco o relatório não é gerado.

```
 $my_where = "where cast(Data_concluido as date) >= $dataInicio AND cast(Data_concluido as date) <= $dataFim AND pes.tipo = $tipo AND pes.Empresa = $empresa" ;

    $my_where = '"' .  $my_where . '"'; 


   $database = [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'username' => 'username',            
        'password' => 'password',            
        'jdbc_driver' => 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver',
        'jdbc_url' => 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/database'
    ];
     $filename = time();

    JasperPHP::process(base_path() . '/app/reports/PesagemEntrada.jasper', 
    base_path() . '/app/reports/PesagemEntrada.jasper' . $filename,
    array("pdf"), //array("pdf", "rtf"), para gerar pdf e word  
    array("my_where" =>  $my_where), 
    $database
    )->execute();
```

Tentei dessa forma também :

```
 JasperPHP::process(base_path() . '/app/reports/PesagemEntrada.jasper', 
    base_path() . '/app/reports/PesagemEntrada.jasper' . $filename,
    array("pdf"), //array("pdf", "rtf"), para gerar pdf e word  
    array("my_where" =>  $my_where), 
    \Config::get('database.connections.sqlsrv')
    )->execute();
```

A query do meu jrxml:

```
    <queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT                                         
                                pes.Cod_pesagem,
                                pes.Peso_bruto,
                                pes.Peso_tara,
                                pes.Peso_liquido,
                                pes.Peso_rejeito,
                                pes.tipo,                                     
                                CONVERT(nvarchar(30), pes.Databruto, 103) as Databruto,
                                CONVERT(nvarchar(30), pes.Datatara, 103) as Datatara,
                                pes.Placa,              
                                pn.cod_pn,
                                pn.parceiros_negocio,
                                prod.Cod_Produto,
                                prod.Produto,
                                motor.cod_motorista,
                                motor.motorista,
                                emp.cod_empresa,
                                emp.empresa

                                        FROM
                                        PESAGEM pes
                                        INNER JOIN EMPRESA as emp ON (pes.Empresa = emp.cod_empresa)
                                        INNER JOIN PARCEIRO_NEGOCIO pn ON (pes.Cod_PN = pn.cod_pn)
                                        INNER JOIN PRODUTO prod ON (pes.Cod_Produto = prod.Cod_Produto)
                                        INNER JOIN MOTORISTA motor ON (pes.Cod_Motorista = motor.cod_motorista) 
                                        $P!{my_where}]]>
```

Comment: Porque não cria a conexão com o banco no próprio jasperserver? e no relatório você define qual conexão utilizar. Ah, entendi. Você esta montando o relatório direto do .jasper. Recomendo então pesquisar pelo jasperserver, que é um serviço para gerenciar os relatórios.

Comment: Com o jasperserver o banco de dados já fica salvo é isso?

Comment: Jasperserver é um serviço de repositório de relatórios e datasets. Onde você através do jaspersoft studio desenha o relatório, conecta no dataset e pronto. Ao chamar pela API só passa os parâmetros que API lhe retorna o relatório no formato que deseja. Pesquise sobre, é sensacional esta tecnologia. Esqueça manipular os arquivos .jasper, isso é muito antigo.

Comment: junior qual seria a api indicada pra fazer essa conexão?

Comment: Raphael: community.jaspersoft.com/project/php-client

Comment: Use essa biblioteca https://github.com/geekcom/phpjasper , ela é uma atualização melhorada de uma outra que não funcionava para Laravel 5.1, foi uns amigos e eu que reescrevemos.

Comment: Boa tarde a todos, estou desenvolvendo um projeto puro PHP para gerar o relatório em pdf a partir do arquivo .jrxml , já tem uma versão funcional no GitHub
https://github.com/QuilhaSoft/JasperPHP